# Blender Python Script，serial.serialutil.SerialExpection:could not open port COM3 [Errno5]

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, blender

Arduino Program:

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}
int i;
void loop() {
  for(i=30;i<=35;i++)
   {
     char a=i;
     Serial.println(a);
     delay(1000);
       }
}
```

Blender python script:

```
import bge
import serial
ser=serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate=9600
ser.port=2
ser.timeout=1
ser.open()

scena=bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
cont=bge.logic.getCurrentController()
main_arm=cont.owner
sens=cont.sensors['mySensor']
if sens.positive:
    u=ord(ser.read())
    main_arm.channels['root'].location=[0,u,0]
    main_arm.updata()
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback （most recent call last）：
File ”Text“ ，line7.in（module）
File ”c：\Programe Files\Blender Foundation\Blender \ 2.69 \ python \ lib \ serial \   seriawin32.py“ line59 in open
raise SerialException（”could not open port %s %s“ （self.portstr.ctypes.WinError（）））
serial.serialutil.SerialException：could not open port COM3[Errno5]
```

How can I correct this error?

Comment: does the same python work outside of blender?

Comment: have you tried another port?